# Rmi in Java - Chat Application with need of modification, but How?

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, rmi

I have made java RMI application - Chat.

Chat Class:

```
public class Chat extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatInterface  {

    public String name;
    public ChatInterface client=null;

    public Chat(String n)  throws RemoteException { 
        this.name=n;   
    }
    public String getName() throws RemoteException {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setClient(ChatInterface c){
        client=c;
    }

    public ChatInterface getClient(){
        return client;
    }

    public void send(String s) throws RemoteException{
        System.out.println(s);
    }   
}
```

ChatClient class:

```
    import java.rmi.*;
    import java.rmi.server.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ChatClient {
        public static void main (String[] argv) {
            try {
                System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","127.0.0.1");
                System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
                Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter Your name and press Enter:");
                String name=s.nextLine().trim();
                ChatInterface client = new Chat(name);
                ChatInterface server = (ChatInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/ABC");
                String msg="["+client.getName()+"] got connected";
                server.send(msg);
                System.out.println("[System] Chat Remote Object is ready:");
                server.setClient(client);

                while(true){
                    msg=s.nextLine().trim();
                    msg="["+client.getName()+"] "+msg;                  
                    server.send(msg);
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("[System] Server failed: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

ChatInterface interface:

```
public interface ChatInterface extends Remote{
    public String getName() throws RemoteException;
    public void send(String msg) throws RemoteException;
    public void setClient(ChatInterface c)throws RemoteException;
    public ChatInterface getClient() throws RemoteException;
}
```

ChatServer class:

```
public class ChatServer {
    public static void main (String[] argv) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","127.0.0.1");
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Your name and press Enter:");
            String name=s.nextLine().trim();

            Chat server = new Chat(name);   

            Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/ABC", server);

            System.out.println("[System] Chat Remote Object is ready:");

            while(true){
                String msg=s.nextLine().trim();
                if (server.getClient()!=null){
                    ChatInterface client=server.getClient();
                    msg="["+server.getName()+"] "+msg;
                    client.send(msg);
                }   
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[System] Server failed: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Chat - the same code in both projects

ChatInterface - the same code in both projects too

ChatClient - ChatServer - they ones that have different code

---

It looks like this: [How it looks inside Eclipse (hierarchy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfQpg.jpg)

And problem is, that this chat works something like...
We got all messages (like whole history) but when user send new message.
For example, we have user1, user2, user3.

- User1 send message: 'FUN!!!'
- User2 and User3 see nothing.
- User2 send "okkk"
- Now user1 sees still only "FUN!!!"
- User2 see "FUN!!!" and "okkk"

And User3 sees nothing, cuz didn't send any message, so have nothing.

And that's bad :/. It's like user have to send something to get messages. Even only "space", but still something. Otherwise he won't get any message.

I need to make this to automatically send all users new messages when they are send by one user. Like "update".'

It needs to be like

- User1 got nothing
- User2 got nothing
- User3 got nothing
- Users3 sends 'AAAA'
- All users have now 'AAAA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface ChatInterface extends Remote{
    public String getName() throws RemoteException;
    public void send(String msg) throws RemoteException;
    public void setClient(ChatInterface c)throws RemoteException;
    public ChatInterface getClient() throws RemoteException;
}
```

The problem starts here. The nature of `setClient()` is that the server only knows about one client at a time. Surely the server should have a *list* of clients, and the method should be `addClient(ChatInterface c)`.

The purpose of `getClient()` as a remote method eludes me.

Comment: I'm starting to understand. And how to send this message to all clients? so they have chat updated?

Comment: Iterate over the list of clients.